# Is it okay to upload a binary 'source' archive to Launchpad for building?

Tags: ppa, launchpad, binary

I have a package that is extremely complicated and uses libraries not included in any of the default repos.

Can I upload a 'source' archive that contains the source and a pre-compiled binary? The build script would simply copy the binary to the package being built.

Is this acceptable or will I run into trouble?

**Note:** [This](https://launchpad.net/chromify-osd) is the project page.

Comment: just something to think about...to address compilation woes like this, one project I am aware of(not in PPA) mplayer, places the build requirements in subdirectories of the source package and lets you use or not use them via a complicated configure script

Comment: @aking: Well, it's a possibility. In the end, I will have to create a package for the library.

Answer (score 1):

Launchpad's [PPA terms of use](https://help.launchpad.net/PPATermsofUse) don't explicitly prohibit a Debian "source" package that contains a pre-compiled binary. It does require the use of an acceptable license (i.e [OSI Approved](http://opensource.org/licenses/category), [FSF Approved](http://www.fsf.org/licensing/licenses/), or [DFSG Compliant](http://www.debian.org/social_contract#guidelines)). So as far as I can tell, the real question is whether the licences of the pre-compiled libraries allow you to distribute them without the corresponding sources.

Of course, if you hope to have your package included in the proper Ubuntu archives this is prohibited. All packages in the archive must be build from source.

Comment: Well, the source is being uploaded with the binary, so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You need to package and upload the libraries first then.

Comment: Sigh... this is gonna take some time.

Answer (score 0):

Technically there should be no problem, from a license point of view you may be violating LP's PPAs use policy, you would be distributing a binary without the corresponding source.

Comment: But I said in the question that the source went along with it.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part, that should be fine, not something that would be accepted in the official repository, but fine for a PPA.